# Take website offline but not API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET MVC web site which also has WEB API and OData end points. Is there a way to take the site offline but keep the API and OData working?

I tried placing an App_Offline.htm on the root, but that made all areas offline.

Comment: 1) first: always make mvc and api like 2 projects - then you will can just stop site in IIS.

2) In your case maybe very easy - it just comment routing for site??

Comment: @David, thanks for the comment. I now know that, but when this whole thing started a while back it hadn't occur to me. So for the time being i am stuck with this structure (until it changes)

Comment: @David i could add a filter to temporary redirect to a custom view (302), but i am trying to avoid redeploying. Ap_Offline is a convenient way, but would make services useless too. My question is if there is another convenient way to bring only the vies offline but not the services.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write a `ActionFilterAttribute` and register it as global filter:

```
public class MyFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private string _offlineUrl;
    public MyFilterAttribute(string offlineUrl)
    {
        _offlineUrl = offlineUrl;
    }
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // considering you have a API controller
        // and you have a Boolean app setting named BringMVCRoutesOffline
        // to activate this filter form web.config 
        // in real world scenario you could check area or what URL
        // or route data you want
        if (Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BringMVCRoutesOffline"])
            && filterContext.RouteData.Values.ContainsKey("controller")
            && !filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"]
                .ToString().ToLower() == "api"
            // avoiding infinite loop 
            && filterContext.HttpContext.Request
                .AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath != _offlineUrl)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(_offlineUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

and in the App_Start > FilterConfig add:

```
filters.Add(new MyFilterAttribute("~/error/offline"));
```

Comment: Or if you are looking more convenient way have look to [IIS URL Rewrite extention](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) you could add rewrite rule ether by GUI or web.config

Comment: If you check my comment on my question, this is exactly what i would do if i would like to redeploy the web site. I like that way, but the question was actually if there was another way like App_Offline. I do like this approach and i am already implementing it as it doesn't seem to be another way. Thanks.

Comment: And i would like to add, that since i want API to be available while the MVC is offline, i think you should change the answer to `!filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString() == "Api"` and going a step further, i would also advise `.ToLower() == "api"` or even `.Equals("api",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)`

Comment: I saw it before I had submitted the post. By using Rewrite extension you could do the same without redeploying.

Comment: In any way, this seems like an answer. I have done some research and have not found a way that would serve my need. And i really do not want to mess with IIS. Thanks in any way.

Comment: And also, just to make this answer a bit more complete, i have added another requirement in the `if`. In the way it is currently presented, it would make all calls go to the `~\error\offline` route. But then you wouldn't be able to easily maintain this. A better solution would be to add an app setting in the web.config and check for that. I have named mine `BringMVCRoutesOffline` and the `if` first checks for `Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BringMVCRoutesOffline"])`. Sorry for overcommenting, but lets make this a perfect answer.

Comment: Thank you. I have learned a lot form you. I have updated the post.

Comment: And i have liked it... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Deploy the WEB API and OData endpoints as separate [IIS applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis) so the `App_Offline.htm` can be used to take one application down without affecting the other deployments. You may be able to accomplish this with existing URLs with *nested IIS applications*.